# getting ffmpeg to work with php website error 500 or access denied

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I have two ways without success and different results, with exec method the ffmpeg actually works and creates the output file but then the website crashes with error 500.
if I use the proc_open method then it runs and creates the log file atest.log in the output store folder, but ffmpeg errors at the end with: store\audio_recording_1441120844021u.mp3: Permission denied and doesn't write the file out.

ffmpeg has IUSR full control permissions and those permissions are also on the store folder.

any ideas???

exec method:-

```
 $cmd = "ffmpeg.exe -i C:\\Windows\\Temp\\recordings\\".$filename." -i watermark.mp3 -filter_complex amerge -c:a libmp3lame -q:a 4 store\\".$filename;
 echo exec($cmd, $o, $v);
```

proc_open method:-

```
 $cmd = "ffmpeg.exe -i C:\\Windows\\Temp\\recordings\\".$filename." -i watermark.mp3 -filter_complex amerge -c:a libmp3lame -q:a 4 store\\".$filename;
 $pipes = array();
 $descriptors = array(2 => array('file', 'store\\atest.log', 'a'));

 $p = proc_open($cmd, $descriptors, $pipes);
 $done = 0;
 while (!$done) 
 {
      sleep(1);

      $status = proc_get_status($p);
      if (!$status['running']) $done = 1;

      echo "STEEL RUN\n";
      // some manipulations with "store\\atest.log"

 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the post, Somehow your proc open method works every time for me. only thing i had to change was the sleep to 3 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

For the `exec()` function, adding `-nostdin` to the FFMPEG command did the trick:

```
$cmd = "ffmpeg.exe -nostdin -i C:\\Windows\\Temp\\recordings\\".$filename." -i watermark.mp3 -filter_complex amerge -c:a libmp3lame -q:a 4 store\\".$filename;
```

Comment: I actually been having this issue, the next request to the php server will immediately throw a 500 error. It seems that php redirected the input directly to ffmpeg causing the crash. The `-nostdin` solved it for me as well.